# Do away with SOAP::Lite->service() call

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl, soaplite

I have a fully functional perl script which talks to our SOAP webservice.  Today it does that via the SOAP::Lite->service('.../name?WSDL') and then a call to execute() against the returned value.  They're now locking down the WSDL so when I hit that I get a 403 error back.

I'm looking for pointers on how to change my script so that it no longer uses the WSDL to figure things out.  I *do* have access to the WSDL itself to look at anything I need to know, but the perl script no longer will.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the WSDL file, you can use the local copy of it to drop right in with no other changes to your code:

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite->service("file:localcopy.wsdl");
```

If you don't mind switching to [SOAP::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/~swalters/SOAP-WSDL/), it includes `wsdl2perl.pl` which will generate all of the perl packages for you:

```
wsdl2perl.pl file:localcopy.wsdl
```

Comment: I don't want to keep a local copy of the file.

Comment: So you're comfortable manually reading the file and updating your packages when the WSDL changes, but not doing so in an automated fashion?  I'm confused.